# Masked images not displaying in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, starling-framework

I am trying to mask an image on another so that I only view the specific portion of the unmasked image through the masked one. My problem is that I cannot see anything on the screen.. no Image, no effect at all

```
cardMask = new Image(Root.assets.getTexture("card_mask"));
cardMask.y = Constants.STAGE_HEIGHT*0.40; 
cardMask.x = Constants.STAGE_WIDTH *0.48; 
trace("it's add mask"); 
cardLight = new Image(Root.assets.getTexture("card_light_mask"));
cardLight.y = Constants.STAGE_HEIGHT*0.46; 
cardLight.x =  Constants.STAGE_WIDTH *0.48; 
cardLight.mask=cardMask;  
maskedDisplayObject = new PixelMaskDisplayObject(-1,false);
maskedDisplayObject.addChild(cardLight); 
maskedDisplayObject.x=cardLight.x; 
maskedDisplayObject.y=cardLight.y; 
maskedDisplayObject.mask=cardMask; 
maskedDisplayObject.blendMode = BlendMode.SCREEN;
addChild(maskedDisplayObject);
```

Comment: Please explain what you desire. Apparently `maskedDisplayObject` should be visible at all times, and `cardLightMask` should be an image that's being "seen through". Right? Also make sure no display object is used to mask more than a single object, [masking](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#mask) explicitly states that one display object assigned to mask multiple objects will only mask the last one. Also check what is `this` of the code provided, and `this.stage` is not null.

Comment: yeah, maskedDisplayObject should be visible at all times but it's not. nothing is being displayed on the screen..

Answer (score 0):

First, for masking an object the `mask` object should also be added to the display list. Your code does not add `cardMask` to display list anywhere. Second, if your `maskedDisplayObject` should be visible at all times, the mask should be assigned not to it, but to some other object which displayed part you desire to control. And third, it is also possible that `this.stage` is null, therefore the entire tree (`this -> maskedDisplayObject -> cardLight`) is plain not rendered. You need to check all three of these conditions to get something displayed.

Also, if you desire `cardLight` as an object to move independently of `maskedDisplayObject`, you should add it to `this` instead, and check that it's displayed on top of `maskedDisplayObject` (call `addChild(cardLight)` after `addChild(maskedDisplayObject)`).

This all totals to this code:

```
trace("Stage is null:", (this.stage==null)); // if this outputs true, you're out of display
cardMask = new Image(Root.assets.getTexture("card_mask"));
cardMask.y = Constants.STAGE_HEIGHT*0.40; 
cardMask.x = Constants.STAGE_WIDTH *0.48; // mask creation unaltered
trace("it's add mask"); 
cardLight = new Image(Root.assets.getTexture("card_light_mask"));
cardLight.y = Constants.STAGE_HEIGHT*0.46; 
cardLight.x =  Constants.STAGE_WIDTH *0.48; 
cardLight.mask=cardMask;  // this is right
maskedDisplayObject = new PixelMaskDisplayObject(-1,false);
// maskedDisplayObject.addChild(cardLight); this is moved to main part of display list
maskedDisplayObject.x=cardLight.x; 
maskedDisplayObject.y=cardLight.y; 
// maskedDisplayObject.mask=cardMask; NO masking of this, you're only masking cardLight
cardLight.blendMode = BlendMode.SCREEN; // display mode is also changed
addChild(maskedDisplayObject);
addChild(cardLight);
```